# fadeIn on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I have a problem in my code. I am trying to display a loading animation(that i have at .gif format). The only problem is that when ever I click the button the animation is being displayed for less than one second and it disappears. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <button id="act">Click me</button>
</form>
<div class="loading"></div><!--my Animation-->
```

Jquery:

```
   $(function() {
    $(".loading").css("display","none");
    $("#act").click(function() {
         $(".loading").fadeIn("slow");
    });

   });
```

Thank you!

Comment: instead of "slow" try giving a value like 3000.. this would be milli seconds.. so give a value accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You'll stop the default action for the sumbit button (submiting the form), you'll need add the `e` parameter to the function and stop the default action.

```
 $(function() {
    $(".loading").css("display","none");
    $("#act").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault(); //This will stop it.
         $(".loading").fadeIn("slow");
    });

   });
```

Comment: I was about to post this after preparing a fiddle - [here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/umjUN/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure but I think the display,none is giving you trouble. Rather hard code this into the css and have it as $(".loading").show() or hide() whenever necessary. First click show and then you can choose when to hide and when to show manually. More flexible.

Comment: the problem with .show() or .hide() is the animation. i guess he wants a fadeIn() effect.

Comment: You could try playing with the timing as Bhushan Kawadkar said or just use the hide effect and the fadeIn(milliseconds here) when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

change like this.

```
$("#act").click(function() {
$(".loading").css("display", "block").css("opacity", "0");
$(".loading").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use miliseconds for fadeIn directly

```
$(".loading").fadeIn(2000);// this will fadin in 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

add an inline display:none; style for the .loading element and remove the css("display","none") from the function

Answer (score 0):

Though the JQuery solutions are very simple, I would look into CSS3 animations. They are much smoother than the built in fadein functionality.